# Unable to identify elements using Appium inspector for ios

Tags: ios, selenium, automation, appium, appium-ios

I am using Appium 1.6.5
Device : iPod
iOS version : 10.3.3

I am unable to identify elements using Appium inspector.
I click on any objects, the whole frame is getting selected.I am not able to identify each element uniquely.Please refer the below image for actual representation of the issue.

Please help me out with the solution

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why don't you try the [latest Appium Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases) that uses Appium server v **1.7.1**

However, if there are some reason behind not using the latest appium server, you can go to web alternative: [Appium-iOS-Inspector](https://github.com/mykola-mokhnach/Appium-iOS-Inspector)